# JavaFX: how to call a method from Controller in Main

Tags: javafx, controller, chess, gridpane

I want to call the method getRow() inside Controller from the main method of class Main in JavaFX. I really have no idea how to use JavaFX so I don't even know if that's something you should do with Controller.

```
public class Controller {

    public Button button00 = new Button();

    public int getRow(){
        return GridPane.getRowIndex(button00);
    }
}
```

I'm making chess in JavaFX (GridPane with 64 buttons) but I already have made a chess as a normal Java project and so I want to somehow make it work with JavaFX. But my original code needs the position of the selected playing piece (which in there was entered from the console) so i tried to get the position of the button which is selected. However I need that position in my main method and I don't know how to get it.

Comment: No you should not be calling it in your main method, you should be calling it in a event in your controller. Can you describe what you are trying to do

Comment: 1. You can't call it from the `main()` method; there is simply no way to get a reference to any controller instance there. 2. There is no need to: in fact, you simply *shouldn't* try to do this. Why not just call the method from `start()` (if you need to call it when the app starts up, for some reason)?

Comment: I'm making chess in JavaFX but I already have made a chess as a normal Java project and so I want to somehow make it work with JavaFX. But my original code needs the position of the selected playing piece so i tried to get the position of the button which is selected. However I need that position in my main method and I don't know how to get it.

Comment: Again, you can't get it in the main method. That method shouldn't be doing any real work anyway.

Comment: @James_D He does not want to get into the Main method rather access the Controller from the Main method instead

Comment: @koulini I know. It says that in the question. As I stated earlier, there is no way to get access to any of the controller instances (plural, note) that will be created when FXML file(s) are loaded.

Comment: @James_D My answer's code does just that (unless I have misunderstood the problem). I am using this methodology in several JavaFX projects and it works great. Please add a comment explaining why, if you believe otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You can get Controller from FXMLLoader:

```
//loading scene fxml
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("your_path.fxml"));
Parent sceneFXML = loader.load();
//getting controller object
Controller ctrl = (Controller)(loader.getController());
```

Now you can access needed attributes or methods from `ctrl`.

```
ctrl.getRow();
```